# MVC ActionLink goes to Get Action Controller Instead of Post Controller with the same name

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC ActionLink which goes to a controller action called `Register`.

I have two `Register` actions, one which is marked with `HttpGet` and the other with `HttpPost`, however when I attempt to post to this action it goes to the GET `Register` method and not the POST action.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Home", new { @class = "btn btn-default" }, new { onclick = "RegisterLoader()" })                                      
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the script

```
function RegisterLoader() {
    var url = '@Url.Action("Register", "Home", new { FormMethod.Post })';
    $("#divLoading").show();

    $.post(url, null,
            function (data) {
                $("#PID")[0].innerHTML = data;
                $("#divLoading").hide();
            });
    }
```

And my controller looks like this.

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    var towns = new List<string> { "Alberton", "Bedfordview", "Benoni", "Boksburg", "Brakpan", "Edenvale", "Germiston", "Kempton Park", "Nigel", "Springs" };
    //var townOptions = new SelectList(towns);
    ViewBag.Town = new SelectList(towns); //townOptions;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem in js, it firstly handle `onclick` event, creates ajax POST request and then change page location to the address, defined at `href` with GET request.

To prevent relocation, you should return `false` from js method:

```
function RegisterLoader() {
    var url = '@Url.Action("Register", "Home",new { FormMethod.Post})';
    $("#divLoading").show();

    $.post(url, null,
            function (data) {
                $("#PID")[0].innerHTML = data;
                $("#divLoading").hide();
            });
    return false;
}
```

It will prevent calling to `href`.

However, if you want to perform synchronous POST request, you should change `ActionLink` to `<input type="submit" />` and wrap the whole form with `form` tag as following (in razor syntax):

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Register", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @*another form tags*@
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
             <input type="submit" value="Register" />

        </div>
    </div>
}
```

P.S. `FormMethod.Post` in `Url.Action` is useless, it renders in the string `"/Home/Register?Post=Post"`